How to connect Conversations to an external endpoint using WhatsApp?
Ok, this is not an easy situation to explain. I will try my best to make it clear.
I am using Studio in Twilio to create a Flow.
In this tool you have some connections that you can make by simple dragging a line to the next widget, for example: "Incoming Message", "Incoming call" and "Incoming Conversation" can be connected with a TwiML widget.
Twilio Studio with main connection widget
I wanted to create something custom. So I created a VM on Azure and opened an endpoint for calls and other for messages. On the flow I just added a TwiML widget, connected it to "incoming call" and putted my API endpoint there. Worked like a charm. Then, I did the same for (whatsapp) message. Created another TwiML widget, connected to "Incoming Message" and it worked just fine.
However, now I want to do the same with "Incoming Conversation" also coming from whatsapp, I though that the process would be the same. But it is not working at all.
I tried to use this tutorial, but it is missing the flow part
I tried to use "Say" widget and got an initial message, but my VM did not catch the conversation.
I found some conversations stuck and deleted it by using flow log. Still not working. But the say widget sent me a message again.
Then I used the Twilio API to search for other stuck conversations, deleted then too. Did not help at all.
It is not clear what is the main difference between message and conversation flows. And thus, how to deal with each one.
Now I am not sure what to do.
Btw, I am using python on the backend.
